# How to create a file of user names in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi I am trying to create a highscores screen for my libgdx game.  I have been able to create a local file for the actual highscores themselves but I am unsure of how to create a file of usernames to accompany the highscores.  For the highscores I created a file with an array of bytes and simply draw them out in the correct order.  I can get the users name as a string but I don't know how to save it to a file so I can easily order it and display it with the highscores.  The only thing I can think of is creating a separate preferences file for each of the top 5 highscores and then display and change each as necessary but that seems like a waste.  Is there anyway I can create a file with the top 5 names/Strings and load them into an array and draw/order from there?  Thanks.

```
Numbers.writeBytes(new byte[]{0,0,0,0,0}, false);//This is how I write a file of the top 5 highscores.  An array of bytes.  This is easy to order and display but I cant do this with Strings.  What could I do to achieve the same with Strings/names.  Thanks
```

Comment: If I created an array of Strings then I could probably loop through the array and write each String to the file.  Then to read I could probably parse the file and put each word into the Array.  Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

The Libgdx [`Preferences` API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html) provides a simple, high-level API for persistent storage of data like high scores.  Its a simple key+value API, so you just need to make keys like "name0" and "score0" for each of the 5 (or 10 or whatever) scores you want to track.

### Saving 5 scores

```
// Assumes names is an array of String names, 
// and scores is an array of integer scores.

Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("highscores");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    prefs.putString("name"+i, names[i]);
    prefs.putInteger("score"+i, scores[i]);

}
prefs.flush();
```

### Loading 5 scores

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("highscores");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    names[i] = prefs.getString("name"+i, null);
    scores[i] = prefs.getInteger("score"+i, 0);

}
```